# jQuery Lightbox plugin influencing ALL <a> tags

Tags: jquery, html, image, hyperlink, lightbox

I've added a lightbox jQuery script and all is working soooo BEAUTIFULLY, until I realised that this script add the lightbox script to ALL  tags on my website. This is a major pain if I want buttons, images, headings, logos, whatever to link to an HTML page within a document :(

Is is possible to change something in the jQuery code that would allow me to add a class or id to the images only that I want to lightbox to be applied to and not every  tag inlcuding my navigation?

Or is the only other option to add a total different lightbox that what I already have?

Here's the site I'm currently working on:
http://www.isabelleroux.co.za/newsite/
The jQuery code can be found in the source....

The only way I can get a button to link without the lightbox is by using:
onclick="MM_goToURL('parent','page.html');return document.MM_returnValue"
but this also has it's limitations and I would prefer NOT to use this anymore....

I'm desperate please!
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, you've this in your script:

```
$('#gallery a').lightBox();
```

It would toggle lightbox on for all elements matching the selector. That is, all `<a>` elements which are inside some element with `id="gallery"`.

One of the ways to fix this is to give *only* the `<a>` elements for which you'd like to turn lightbox on a more specific classname like so:

```
<a class="lightbox">
```

Then you can use the following selector:

```
$('#gallery a.lightbox').lightBox();
```

or even this:

```
$('a.lightbox').lightBox();
```

#### See also:

- [jQuery tutorial - Using selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aGetting_Started_with_jQuery#Find_me%3a_Using_selectors_and_events)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your html is annotated with classes you can have the JQuery select only specific classes to apply the plug-In to.

`$(".SomeClassYouWantToApplyJQueryTo").[SomeJQueryFunctionCall]`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
        $('#gallery a:has(img)').lightBox();
});
```

would fix the problem. It makes sure that the a contains an image. But i would consider using a class to avoid further problems.